# Daily populating a table by another one SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to populate a table by another one (which will get truncate after), however when I used this it's only a ONE shot because SQL says that the table exist already. I just want to add rows into that Alberta table.

```
USE [DATAWAREHOUSE]
GO


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER Procedure [dbo].[prcAlberta] As 

(
Select *
INTO AlbertaData_Storing
FROM dbo.AlbertaData_import
where name is not null )

truncate table AlbertaData_import
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error occurred because command insert all into 'TableName' from another table create a new table with schema. So that need to change the query  like this.

```
USE [DATAWAREHOUSE]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[prcAlberta] 
AS 
BEGIN
    /* If the table not exist then create a blank table */
    IF OBJECT_ID('AlbertaData_Storing') IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT * INTO AlbertaData_Storing
        FROM  dbo.AlbertaData_import WHERE 1 <> 1
    END
    /* 
    Better to use required column only Like :
    INSERT INTO AlbertaData_Storing(Column1,Column2,Column3,...)
    SELECT Column1,Column2,Column3,... FROM dbo.AlbertaData_import
    WHERE Name IS NOT NULL
    */
    INSERT INTO AlbertaData_Storing
    SELECT * FROM dbo.AlbertaData_import
    WHERE Name IS NOT NULL

    TRUNCATE TABLE AlbertaData_import
END                       
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest dropping the table and then inserting into it:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[prcAlberta] A
as
begin
    begin try
        drop table AlbertaData_Storing;
    end try
    begin catch  -- do nothing
    end catch;

    select *
    into AlbertaData_Storing
    from dbo.AlbertaData_import
     where name is not null

    truncate table AlbertaData_import
end;
GO
```