# How do I update a SQL table with daily records?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL database where some of my tables are updated daily. I want to create another table which is updated daily with records of what tables (table name, modified/updated date) were updated. I also do not want this table to get too big, so I want this table to only keep records for the last 31 days. How would I write the code for this?

I have already created a table (tUpdatedTables) but i would like this table to be updated daily & keep these records for 31 days

This is how I created the table

```
Select *

Into tUpdatedTables
from sys.tables
order by modify_date desc
```

I have tried inserting an "Update" code to update the table but I get an error

```
update tUpdatedTables
    set [name]
      ,[object_id]
      ,[principal_id]
      ,[schema_id]
      ,[parent_object_id]
      ,[type]
      ,[type_desc]
      ,[create_date]
      ,[modify_date]
      ,[is_ms_shipped]
      ,[is_published]
      ,[is_schema_published]
      ,[lob_data_space_id]
      ,[filestream_data_space_id]
      ,[max_column_id_used]
      ,[lock_on_bulk_load]
      ,[uses_ansi_nulls]
      ,[is_replicated]
      ,[has_replication_filter]
      ,[is_merge_published]
      ,[is_sync_tran_subscribed]
      ,[has_unchecked_assembly_data]
      ,[text_in_row_limit]
      ,[large_value_types_out_of_row]
      ,[is_tracked_by_cdc]
      ,[lock_escalation]
      ,[lock_escalation_desc]
      ,[is_filetable]
      ,[is_memory_optimized]
      ,[durability]
      ,[durability_desc]
      ,[temporal_type]
      ,[temporal_type_desc]
      ,[history_table_id]
      ,[is_remote_data_archive_enabled]
      ,[is_external] 
--Into tUpdatedTables
from sys.tables
where modify_date >= GETDATE()
order by modify_date desc
```

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 4 There is already an object named
>   'tUpdatedTables' in the database.

Comment: Apologies, clicked on it in erorr

Comment: actually you need a history table......which keep data upto 30 day?

Comment: select  all into command create a new table with schema and data . Use insert into command like :
`INSERT INTO tUpdatedTables (.....)
SELECT  .....  FROM SourceTable`

Comment: `sys.tables` doesn't contain info you are after. https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Which database technology are you using (e.g. mysql, Oracle, something else)?

Comment: You may see this one -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/56962014/5496498

Comment: What about enabling CDC and set the retention period to 31 days.

Answer (score 0):

> *I want to create another table which is updated daily with records of what tables (table name, modified/updated date) were updated.*

If this is all you want, I would suggest instead simply doing daily backups. You should be doing that anyway.

---

Beyond that, what you're looking for is an audit log. Most languages and frameworks have libraries to do this for you. For example, [paper_trail](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail).

If you want to do this yourself, follow the basic pattern of paper_trail.

- `id` as an autoincrementing primary key
- `item_type` which would be the table, or perhaps something more abstract
- `item_id` is the primary key of the item
- `event` are you storing a create, an update, or a delete?
- `bywho` identify who made the change
- `object` a json field containing a dump of the data
- `created_at` when this happened (use a default)

[Using JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) is key to making this table generic. Rather than trying to store every possible column of every possible table, and having to keep that up to date as the tables change, you store a JSON dump of the row using [`FOR JSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-for-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#for-json). This means the audit table doesn't need to change as other tables change. And it will save a lot of disk space as it avoids the audit table having a lot of unused columns.

For example, here's how you'd record creating ID 5 of `some_table` by user 23. (I might be a bit off as I don't use SQL Server).

```
insert into audit_log (item_type, item_id, event, bywho, object)
values(
  'some_table', 5, 'create', 23, (
    select * from some_table where id = 5 for json auto
  )
)
```

Because the audit table doesn't care about the structure of the thing being recorded, you use insert, update, and delete triggers to each table to record their changes in the audit log. Just change the `item_type`.

As for not getting too big, don't worry about it until it's a problem. Proper indexing means it won't be a problem: a composite index on `(item_type, item_id)` will make listing the changes to a particular thing fast. Indexing `bywho` will make searches for changes made by a particular thing fast. You shouldn't be referencing this thing in production. If you are, that probably requires a different design.

[Partitioning the table by month](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-2017) could also stave off scaling issues.

And if it does get too big, you can backup the table and use `created_at` to delete old entries.

```
delete from audit_log
where created_at < dateadd(day, -31, getdate())
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll have a look and try this